# Change URN in node element WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, soap

everyone.
I'm working on a legacy service that uses URN using message contract and wcf and i have this small but very tricky inconvinient.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:UMARKETSPIWS:v2" xmlns:gps="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GPS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:CreditAirtime>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:transactionId>321321</urn:transactionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:extraParameters>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <gps:KeyValuePairs>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gps:key>?</gps:key>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gps:value>?</gps:value>
            </gps:KeyValuePairs>
         </urn:extraParameters>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:msisdn>50370823063</urn:msisdn>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:amount>5</urn:amount>
      </urn:CreditAirtime>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to change the gps: tag to urn: in the extraParameters section example:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:UMARKETSPIWS:v2" xmlns:gps="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GPS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:CreditAirtime>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:transactionId>321321</urn:transactionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:extraParameters>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <urn:KeyValuePairs>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:key>?</gps:key>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:value>?</gps:value>
            </urn:KeyValuePairs>
         </urn:extraParameters>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:msisdn>50370823063</urn:msisdn>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:amount>5</urn:amount>
      </urn:CreditAirtime>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I alredy try by adding [MessageBodyMember(Name = "key", Order = 0,Namespace = "urn:")] and doesnt apper to be working everything else is working fine but i really don't have any idea where to start with this.

Interface and classes here.
http://pastebin.com/dtjmXQaz

Comment: The namespace should be `"urn:UMARKETSPIWS:v2"` not `"urn:"`.  `urn:` is just a lookup [prefix](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) for the actual namespace.  Beyond that, can you share your classes including `KeyValuePairs` and `extraParameters`?

Comment: Alredy corrected the urn namespace but still can modify the namespace for the keyvalupairs, here is the interface and classes http://pastebin.com/dtjmXQaz thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`MessageContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes only control SOAP formatting for a type that corresponds to a SOAP message envelope -- one of the types appearing directly in your `OperationContract`.  For types that are not mapped to SOAP messages but are only referred to by a root message type, you need to use [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Thus:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "urn:UMARKETSPIWS:v2")]
    public class KeyValuePair
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "key", Order = 0)]
        public string key { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "value", Order = 1)]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

In fact, for simple messages where you don't need precise control of SOAP message formatting or security, you can often just use data contract attributes.  See [Using Message Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Specifying Data Transfer in Service Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much, now i understand the difference between this two types of contract